# Intellij, prevent messages pop up on make build

Tags: intellij-idea

So, I have the autobuild plugin. But, it is annoying that if there are errors, on each save, the messages box with errors keeps popping up. Yes, I know there are errors. Let me take care of them myself. In between I might save. So, leave me alone.

I save to update the errors in the editor. But, I do not need the messages view for that. I can type <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> myself.

Is there a way to disable the messages popup or do I have to shoot myself?

Comment: well, if you shoot yourself, the messages will still pop up. So, don't do that

Comment: Check my solution to similar question on stackowerflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63052360/6564911

Answer (score 2):

I know this one is old, but hopefully this will still help somebody:

Current IDEA version have

Settings => Appearance & Behavior => Notifications

You can fine tune what events cause which type of notification or disable balloon notifications completely.

Answer (score 2):

HYI'm not exactly sure, if this is related, but in AppCode this build messages tool window keeps opening automatically whenever the project gets build.

I'm not aware of an option in `Settings => Appearance & Behavior => Notifications` to turn this off.

Is there a way to avoid this auto-opening of the tool window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can record a macros for run (Control + R) and show/hide Messages window (Option + 0), and set the new binding (Control + R) on that macros.

Macros located on: Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording