# Disable showing of run window in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

In IntelliJ every time I make a change in code and I run the app afterwards, "run window" is automatically popped up. Is there any way to disable this annoying behaviour or how to make it less distracting?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no solution to do this permanently. However, there is a workaround to prevent it from popping up. Try this:

After the first time the window pops-up simply resize it **all the way to the bottom** (i.e. grab the TOP and drag down until the window disappears). This will prevent it from popping up again until you manually click one of the buttons to open **any window in the same area** (i.e. Run, TODO, Android, Terminal, Messages, (and Find Results) - or whatever you have in that same area if you've customized it).

To keep it from popping up, never click the hide button on any of these windows but rather use the same "drag from top to bottom" to hide them (the effect is the same).

This is annoying, to say the least, but once you get used to it it works fine and is much less annoying than dealing with that blasted Run popup window :)

**NOTE**
I should mention that this is completely safe to do as the windows are only hidden when you do this, and clicking the window's button at the bottom will show it in its original size - so nothing goes missing or breaks using this method :-)

Comment: When in floating mode `Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down` roll up/roll out.

Comment: Better than nothing, I guess. I was getting tired of my code-window constantly being covered up.

Answer (score 40):

I finally could solve this one. At least it worked for me. At the bottom of "Run/Debug configurations" window and in "Before launch" part, uncheck "Activate tool window" check box.

[image]

Comment: Upvoted -- this should be the accepted answer now @sealskej

Comment: How do you get to "Run/Debug configurations" shown here?

Answer (score 2):

These are called Tool Windows. Right-click the tool window, it pops up a menu, the last option of which is 'Hide'.

Alternatively,

You can install the plugin [ToolWindow Manager](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=1489) to show/hide the Tool Window of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, but actually none of ways solved the issue - I'd like to hide window permanently, so every time I run app, I shouldn't see the window and it should stay hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Either 
1. Set the run window to be in either split and then shrink it down to be as small as possible.
2. Set the windows to be in floating mode and then shrink it down and move it somewhere less distracting.

Comment: nice hack bro, saved my rare vertical space that i love so much

Answer (score 2):

disabling checkboxes in "Window | Background tasks solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is soooo annoying oO I just dragged the windows to an other screen and/or set their height to a minimum.. Not "best practise" but it is better than nothing -.-

Answer (score 1):

In intellij go to main menu windows->active tool window->disable floating  mode option there.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing this issue with "Run" window they can follow below instruction
From dropdown select "Edit Configuration":
[image: From dropdown select "Edit Configuration"]
Open Logs tab:
[image: Open Logs tab]
Uncheck these 2 checkboxes:
[image: Uncheck these 2 checkboxes]

Comment: FYI: i'm facing this issue on pyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution!!!!

There old plugin for Intellij IDE called **"Hide Tool Window Ex"**.

It hides any tool windows that being opened just after you click in editor again.
(plugin [page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7836-hide-tool-windows-ex/))

[visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvU2q.gif)